# Checking number of reallocated sectors of HDD through Disk Utility, Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility

My MacBook was purchased in 2008. Yesterday I checked the number of reallocated sectors of the hard drive using Disk Utility. It showed there were no reallocated sectors. That seems strange since I haven't replaced my hard drive since 2008. Can I rely on Disk Utility for this information or I need to download additional software?

Comment: Why does it seem strange that your hard drive is functioning normally?

Answer (score 1):

Reallocated sectors frequently (but not always) appear when a hard drive stars to fail. Just a few back-of-the-envelope calculations here:

If you bought your computer in the beginning of 2008 and used it 24 hours a day, you'd have used about 32,000 hours of hard drive time. I don't know what model of hard drive your computer has, but the mean time between failures for not-pariticularly-impressive hard drives from that era is about [300,000 hours](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/apple-macbook-laptop,2130-10.html). So in the heaviest-use scenario, you've used your hard drive for about 10% of its expected life.

I don't think there's anything strange about a lack of failed sectors at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I don't see any relocated sectors for years, then dozens appear at the same time when the disk is about to fail.

I tend to demote disks to being used as backup devices or file transfer disks in an external enclosure after 3 years of active use because that's around the time I find they usually start to fail.